# Codeigniter query updating all rows instead of 1

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I'm having problem in updating a row i'm doing it through ajax, the query is affecting all rows instead of a single id i have given
This is my Model Class function:

```
public function edit_season($data)
{
    // echo $a = json_encode($data);
    // echo $a->id;
    // die();

    $this->db->get_where('seasons', array('season_id ' => 11 ));
    $query = $this->db->update('seasons',array('names ' => $data['name'] ));

    if ($query) 
    {
        return $query;
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

}
```

I have also checked the data i'm getting from ajax is right, but i guess there is some problem with query thing i even hardcoded the id value still it's updating all names instead of one.

Comment: What is the format of $data ? is it a json array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$this->db->where('season_id', 11));
$query = $this->db->update('seasons', array('names ' => $data['name']));
```

This is the right way to put a `where` condition while updating a query.

There is a difference between `get_where` and `where`.

`get_where` will retrieve the data rows from the table, whereas `where` will add a condition

Comment: This is the correct answer. You can also include the where statement directly in the update query: `$query = $rows->update('seasons',array('names ' => $data['name'] ),array('season_id ' => 11 ));`

Comment: @jtheman, exactly. Just tried to give an easy solution for a newbie

Comment: sorry, where is `$rows` defined?

Comment: You will need to replace `$row` with `$this->db`. Have edited the answer

Answer (score 1):

You should not call get_where, use where instead:

```
$this->db->where('season_id', 11);
$query = $this->db->update('seasons',array('names ' => $data['name'] ));
```

You can also do it in one line:

```
$query = $this->db->update('seasons',array('names ' => $data['name']), "season_id = 11");
```

Comment: `where` doesn't need table name as parameter. it either has two parameters with first as column name and second as column value. Or an array with key value pairs where key is the column name and values are the column values

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $this->db->where('seasons', array('season_id ' => 11 ));
 $query =  $this->db->update('seasons',array('names ' => $data['name'] ));
```